# JavaScript Three.js / logic -- how to tween a object from one position to another within a given amount of time with only native JS

Tags: javascript, math, logic, tween

I basically want to be able to move one object from a start position to an end position *within an exact amount of time*, for example move a cube from {x:0, y:0, z:0} to {x:5, y:-3, z:10} in exactly 750 milliseconds. I need to be able to calculate the movement to the exact millisecond in order to line it up with audio properly, so I need to be able to calculate the amount of time it takes from one frame to the next and account that into my equation. I have it almost exactly working, I don't want to paste my entire project since it depends on a few files, but I'll cite the key calculations for what I have so far, but keep in mind that the code below itself is not testable, since it depends on a bunch of other things, but I wanted to just share the general method. In my main file with all of my helper functions I have an update() function setup in a setInterval(update, 1000 / FPS), with FPS being set to 60.

As you may have guessed, it doesn't happen *exactly* 60 times per second, since the browser performance sometimes slows it down by a few dozen milliseconds, or even less, but still. So in my update function, it goes something like this (I wasn't sure what variables to capture, either the literal difference of once frame to the next, or the ratio of difference, so I captured both for now):

```
var lastFrame = Date.now();
    var difference = 0;
    var deltaTime = 0;
    function update() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        raycaster.setFromCamera(
            mouse.position3D, 
            camera
        );

        things.forEach(x => {
            if(x.update) {

                x.update(x);
            }
        });
        //other general update things which take some time etc.
        deltaTime = Date.now() / lastFrame;
        difference = Date.now() - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = Date.now()
    }
```

so as you can see I have all of my THREE.js objects nested in an array of wrapper objects called "things", and each of these "things" has an update function which is called from the main update function. We'll get back to this in a sec., but first the other main helper function (which is the main point of the question), the tween function (still in this general main helper-function file):

```
Object.defineProperties(Object, {
    copy: {
        get() {
            return function(other, other2) {
                if(!(typeof other2 == "object")) {
                    var tmp = {};
                    for(var k in other) {
                        if(typeof other == "object") {
                            tmp[k] = other[k];
                        }
                    }
                    return tmp;
                } else {

                    for(var k in other2) {
                        other[k] = other2[k]
                    }
                    var o2a;
                    if(t(other2, String)) {
                        o2a = other2.split(",");
                    } else if(t(other2, Array)) {
                        o2a = other2
                    }
                //  console.log(o2a)
                    if(t(o2a, Array)) {
                        var r  = {};
                        o2a.forEach(k => {
                            r[k] = other[k];
                        })
                        return r
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }

});

function myTween(opts) { 
    var th = this;
    if(!opts) opts = {};
    this.changeObj = opts.changeObj || {};
    var first = opts.first || {};
    this.second = opts.second || {};
    var originalTotalTime = opts.totalTime || 1000; 
    this.totalTime = originalTotalTime

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        first: {
            get() {
                return first;
            },
            set(v) {
                first = v;
                Object.copy(obj, v);
                th.totalTime = originalTotalTime;
            }
        }
    });
    var rezs = {},
        rez = "going",
        obj = this.changeObj,
        hasReached = false,
        curTotal = this.totalTime;
    Object.copy(obj, first)
    this.reached = () => {
        if(t(opts.reached, Function)) {
            opts.reached(this);
        }
        if(hasReached) {
            curTotal = Date.now() - timeOfLast
            console.log(
                originalTotalTime - curTotal,
                curTotal,
                diff
            );
            timeOfLast = Date.now();
            hasReached = false;
        }

    };

    var lastF = Date.now(),
        diff = 1,
        timeOfLast = lastF,
        totalTime = 0;

    this.update = () => {
        if(!hasReached) {
        //  timeOfLast = Date.now()


            hasReached = true;
        }
        diff = Date.now() - lastF;


        rezs = {};
        rez = ""
        Object.keys(this.first).forEach(k => {

            var distanceNeeded = Math.abs(
                this.first[k] - this.second[k]
            ),

            curDist = Math.abs(obj[k] - this.second[k]),
            stepAmount = (
                ((curDist) /   
                    (
                        this.totalTime * (
                            1
                        )
                    )) * diff
                    *deltaTween * deltaTime
                    /*
                    (
                        (originalTotalTime - this.totalTime) /
                        (this.totalTime)
                    )*/
            ),
            leeway = stepAmount
            //console.log(stepAmount)
            this.totalTime -= diff / Object.keys(this.first).length;
            if(this.totalTime < 0) {
            //  this.reached()
            /// this.totalTime = originalTotalTime;

            }
            var ox = this.second[k];
            if(ox < obj[k] + leeway) {
                stepAmount = -Math.abs(stepAmount);
            } else if (ox > obj[k] - leeway) {
                stepAmount = Math.abs(stepAmount);
            }
            if(curDist < leeway) {
                obj[k] = this.second[k];
                stepAmount = 0;
                rezs[k] = "there";

            }

            obj[k] += stepAmount;
        });

        var count = 0;
        for(var r in rezs) {
            if(rezs[r] == "there") count++;
        }

        if(count > 0) {
            rez = "there";
        } else {
            rez = "going"
        }

        if(rez == "there") {
            this.reached();
        }

        lastF = Date.now();
    };
}
```

so a lot of things are going on in this function, but hopefully some of the details will become apparent once I show how it is used, in another file. Basically when creating a new thing in the "things" array, each "thing" has an update function (which was called earlier from the main update loop) and a start function, so here is how it is utilized:

```
new main.thing({
            color:"blue",
            position: {
                x:-3,
                y:-1
            },
            start(me) {
                me.ok = {

                            x:0,
                            z:-2,
                            y:4,

                        };
                me.ko = {

                            y:-2,
                            x:3,

                            z:3
                        }
                me.done = []
                me.averages = [];
                me.notsoaverage = [];
                me.lolabuy = new main.myTween({
                    changeObj: me.position,
                    first: me.ok,
                    second: me.ko,
                    totalTime: 200,
                    reached(tween) {

                        tween.first = Object.copy(tween.second, "x,y,z");
                        tween.second = {
                            x: Math.random() * 8
                             - 4,
                             z: Math.random() * 8
                             - 6,
                            y: Math.random() * 8
                             - 4,

                        }

                    }
                });
            },
            update(me) {

                me.lolabuy.update()
            }
        });
```

so basically the function from before, myTween, is actually a constructor, and in the start, it sets a new myTween to the "me" object, which refers to the "things" (wrapper fro THREE.js object) itself. The "first" of the tween is set to "me.ok", which represents the starting position, and the "second", which represents the position it is going to tween to, is set to the variable "me.ko", and when it reaches it (as called from the function "reached") it resets tween.first to the old me.ko (a.k.a., changing the new start position to the old end position) and sets tween.second to a new randomly generated position, and it keeps repeating and console.log-ing the time it takes from one to the other. (and as you might have guessed "totalTime" is the amount of time it's supposed to take between one tween and the other).

It almost works perfectly accurately, except its usually about 16 milliseconds either too less or too much (which is about 1000/60), or sometimes a few less or more milliseconds off. This is a problem as I need this to be exact to the millisecond.

If all of the code above is too complex to get, the key part of the entire code is this:

```
stepAmount = (
                    ((curDist) /   
                        (
                            this.totalTime * (
                                1
                            )
                        )) * diff
                        *deltaTween * deltaTime
                        /*
                        (
                            (originalTotalTime - this.totalTime) /
                            (this.totalTime)
                        )*/
                )
```

to calculate properly the correct stepAmount to take per frame in the tween.

And it goes without saying that I'm **not** interested in using any libraries such as tween.js etc.

Answer (score 0):

most tween engines don't use a stepAmount nor do they keep any state (or not much state). They just have a startTime and duration (or endTime and compute duration).

So first you convert that to a normalized (0 to 1) number.

```
t = (currentTime - startTime) / duration
```

You then modify t by an [easing function](https://www.google.com/search?q=easing+function),

```
t = easingFunc(t)
```

You can then compute the tweened value

```
value = startValue + (endValue - startValue) * t
```

No state is needed. For a given value of `time` you'll always get the same result.

This lets you "scrub" time to show any state of the animation.

They then have options for how to handle `t` before and after duration. Common options are

- let t just continue
- loop in place

  ```
  t = t % 1
  ```
- stop at the ends

  ```
  t = max(min(t, 1), 0)
  ```
- ping pong

  ```
  t = (t % 2) < 1 ? t : 2 - t;
  ```

etc...

After that you need options to decide what to do when t = 1 like remove the that animation from the list of running animations or call a function etc...

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const startValue = {x:0, y:0, z:0};
const endValue = {x:5, y:-3, z:10};
const duration = 750;
const startTime = 0;

function process(time) {
  // compute a normalized t value
  let t = (time - startTime) / duration;

  // remember if we hit 1.0 before doing the rest
  const isAtEnd = t >= 1;
  
  // decide how to handle t outside the current range
  t = t % 1;  // this is loop
  
  // apply easing
  t = easingFunc(t);
  
  // compute value
  const v = lerp3(startValue, endValue, t);
  
  // do something if we are at the end
  if (isAtEnd) {
     // remove tween from list of tweens?
     // call callback that tween is over?
     // chain to next tween?
     // etc...
  }
  
  // use value
  draw(v); 
}

function lerp3(start, end, t) {
  return {
    x: lerp(start.x, end.x, t),
    y: lerp(start.y, end.y, t),
    z: lerp(start.z, end.z, t),
  };
}

function lerp(start, end, t) {
  return start + (end - start) * t;
}

function easingFunc(t) {
  return t;  // just linear
}

function loop(time) {
  process(time);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);

function draw(v) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  
  const scale = 300 / 10;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  ctx.translate(1, 5);
  
  const size = v.z / 10;  // some rep for Z
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(v.x, v.y, size, size);
  
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

There are a few edge cases to deal with. For example if you have the ping pong option maybe you want a callback for when t = 1 and when t = 0 again.

Another is distguishing from `t >= 1` (which might be every frame) and `oldT < 1 && newT >= 1` which will happen once. You can store oldTime globally

```
   oldT = (oldTime - startTime) / duration;
   t = (time - startTime) / duration;

   isAtEnd = oldT < 1 && t >= 1;
```

You say you don't want to use a tween library which is fine but you can look inside one to see what they are doing when writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

@gman has done a great job at explaining how this can work.

I'd like to offer a solution that uses a "step-based" tween

```js
class Tween {
    constructor ({from, to, change, steps, easeFn, duration, cb}) {
        this.from = from
        this.to = typeof to === 'undefined' ? from + change : to
        this.change = typeof change === 'undefined' ? to - from : change
        this.steps = steps
        this.step = 0
        this.duration = duration
        this.easeFn = typeof easeFn !== 'function' ? t => t : easeFn
        this.cb = typeof cb === 'undefined' ? () => {} : cb
        this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }

    tick () { this.step < this.steps && this.step++ }

    update (now) {
        if (now > this.endTime) return this.stop()
        this.requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
        if (this.step < (now / this.endTime) * this.steps | 0) {
            this.tick()
            this.cb(this.value)
        }
    }

    start () {
        this.startTime = window.performance.now()
        this.endTime = this.startTime + this.duration
        this.requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
    }

    get value () {
        return this.from + (this.to - this.from) * this.easeFn(this.step / this.steps)
    }

    stop () { if (this.requestId) window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestId) }
}
```

I've built it so that you can use either and absolute end value, or a change in value of the `from` property.

The `cb` property is what will be called with the value of the tween as it updates.

I've even thrown in an optional `easeFn` property so you can ease the value whilst still allowing the stepped nature of this tween class.

```js
// Example One (Using `from` and `to`)
const exampleOne = new Tween({
    from: -10,
    to: 0,
    steps: 5,
    duration: 1000,
    cb: v => console.log(v)
}).start()

// Example Two (Using `from` and `change`)
const exampleTwo = new Tween({
    from: -10,
    change: 10,
    steps: 5,
    duration: 1000,
    cb: v => console.log(v)
}).start()

// Example Three (Using `easeFn`)
const exampleThree = new Tween({
    from: 0,
    to: 10,
    steps: 5,
    duration: 1000,
    cb: v => console.log(v),
    easeFn: t => t < .5 ? Math.pow(t, 2) / 2 : (1 - Math.pow(1 - (t * 2 - 1), 2)) / 2 + .5
}).start()
```

If you have any more questions please let me know